# Calling a stored procedure from java that accepts parameter of type Record

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I want to write a simple insert statement in an Oracle stored procedure. The target table has 40 columns. So rather than passing all parameters to the procedure one by one, I am planning to accept an input parameter of type Record %rowtype at procedure level .

My questions are,

1. Is it possible in first place?
2. If yes, how can I call this procedure from Java code and pass input of type record?

Comment: You could try this solution https://community.oracle.com/thread/936596

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something similar with java.sql.SQLData and Oracle object types.

The sqldata object's writeSQL method creates a serialized stream of data that maps to the fields of the Oracle object.

The reverse mapping is handled by the readSQL method.